# 2022 Community Moderation Election Results

Tags: discussion, moderators, election

Parenting's [third moderator election](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/election/3) has come to a close, the votes have been tallied, and the new moderator is:

[image: anongoodnurse]

They'll be joining [the existing crew](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators) shortly — please thank them for volunteering, and share your assistance and advice with them as they learn the ropes!

Please join me in thanking SomeShinyObject who is stepping down at this time. They've been a wonderful addition to the team and I hope they'll continue to be a part of this site for years to come.

For details on how the voting played out, you can download the election results [here](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/election/3), or [view a summary report online](https://www.opavote.com/results/6734007665426432).

Answer (score 5):

Welcome back @anongoodnurse, and sorry to see you leave the mod group @someshinyobject.

Comment: I'll still be lurking. Thanks for all the advice and insights throughout my time.. It was a good experience.

Comment: Thanks! And thank you, @SomeShinyObject, for moderating. Enjoy the freedom!